# Change XAML control from a different xaml file

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have 2 XAML files: MainPage.xaml and Settings.XAML

I'd like to change the MainPage.xaml LayoutRoot.Background property from the Settings.XAML. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a ResourceDictionary.  Create a new xaml file (e.g. Style.xaml) in your project with these contents

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationFramework">

    <Color x:Key="MainBackGroundColor">#F6F5E0</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Update App.xaml like this. By the way if you want to split your settings into different files you can put each file in this MergedDictionaries section.

```
<Application x:Class="SonoCine.CineReader.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Style.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Now you should be able to use MainBackGroundColor in your MainPage.xaml like this

Background="{StaticResource MainBackGroundColor}"

Comment: I am a bit confused by the first step.
Do I just copy paste the code somewhere in the xaml file?
And where?
btw this is how my settings.xaml looks like: http://pastebin.com/PMyPSDis

Comment: You should be able cut/paste the ResourceDictionary xml into a new file called Settings.xaml.  For the App.xaml file you can cut/paste just this <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Settings.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.
        </ResourceDictionary> and place it in between the <Application.Resources>. Then do this to your xaml <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource MainBackGroundColor">

Comment: But the Settings.xaml file already exists. So if I delete that, then I also lose the layout.

Comment: I see.  Didn't realize you already had a Settings.xaml. Ok just to make it easier maybe create a new xaml file called Style.xaml and paste the entirety of the ResourceDictionary into Style.xaml.  In you App.xaml xml instead of using Settings.xaml on the Source attribute use Style.xaml

Comment: I did what you said. Now my App.xaml looks like this: http://pastebin.com/0HWRs6Vd

But I get a few errors. 

- Error 1 The member "DispatcherUnhandledException" is not recognized or is not accessible.

- Error 12 Each dictionary entry must have an associated key.

Comment: Ok first remove DispatcherUnhandledException="HandleMainUIThreadExceptions" from the <Application> element. Sorry I missed that when I copied from my app. Then cut the <Style x:Key="PanoramaItemHeaderTextStyle"> from App.xaml and put it in Style.xaml instead.

Comment: Allright I removed it. I just hove this error now: Error 1 Each dictionary entry must have an associated key.

And are you sure I should create a new XAML file and not a resources file (.resx)?

Comment: I am positive that a ResourceDictionary in a xaml file will work because I have several apps doing just that. The key error is due to your app.xaml also containing the <Style x:Key="PanoramaItemHeaderTextStyle">. That should be moved to the Style.xaml file. You will probably need to move the font size constant to the style file as well.  When you do that you will need to add xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" to the <ResourseDictionary> element in the style file.

Comment: So I just make a new XAML file, delete everything it has and replace it with the <ResourceDictionary> elements?

Comment: In VS R-Click the proj and select Add New Item. In the item tree select WPF and then select the Resource Dictionary(WPF) template.  Name it Style.xaml.  Just add the <Color> element I described above.

Comment: But it's not for WPF, it's for Windows Phone

Comment: Should work either way. All it does it create the xaml file. You don't have to use the template.  You could just create an empty xaml file and copy/paste all of the ResourceDictionary xml I show above into it. That would work as well. Here is a gist which you should be able to copy paste from exactly. https://gist.github.com/pdoh00/11259980

Comment: Any luck with the gist I provided Arn?  Were you able to get your background color working on the phone?

Comment: Yeah it kinda worked. Not entirely, but I googled a bit and had to change a few things but it works